# How can i target properties in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm building a simple card game in vanilla JS.

I have an array of card objects:

```js
let cards = [
    {value: "4", suit: "Hearts", weight: 4, cardFace: "&#127156;"},
    {value: "K", suit: "Clubs", weight: 10, cardFace: "&#127199;"}
]
```

How can I target all `cardFace` properties at any index in `cards` so that I can display them in my HTML document?

I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: What do you mean by targetting ?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method

```
let cards = [
    {value: "4", suit: "Hearts", weight: 4, cardFace: "&#127156;"},
    {value: "K", suit: "Clubs", weight: 10, cardFace: "&#127199;"}
];

let result = Array.from(cards, card => card.cardFace);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access them directly:

```js
let cards = [
    {value: "4", suit: "Hearts", weight: 4, cardFace: "&#127156;"},
    {value: "K", suit: "Clubs", weight: 10, cardFace: "&#127199;"}
]

console.log(cards[0].cardFace);
console.log(cards[1].cardFace);
```

You can also do this in an index-based `for` loop:

```js
let cards = [
  {value: "4", suit: "Hearts", weight: 4, cardFace: "&#127156;"},
  {value: "K", suit: "Clubs", weight: 10, cardFace: "&#127199;"}
];

for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  console.log(cards[i].cardFace);
}
```

Another option is a `for ... of` loop, which is more readable imo. This one also uses ES6' *Object destructuring*:

```js
let cards = [
  {value: "4", suit: "Hearts", weight: 4, cardFace: "&#127156;"},
  {value: "K", suit: "Clubs", weight: 10, cardFace: "&#127199;"}
];

for (const { cardFace } of cards) {
  console.log(cardFace);
}
```

You can also create a new array from `cards` which has only the color values:

```js
let cards = [
    {value: "4", suit: "Hearts", weight: 4, cardFace: "&#127156;"},
    {value: "K", suit: "Clubs", weight: 10, cardFace: "&#127199;"}
]

const colors = cards.map(card => card.cardFace);

console.log(colors); // ["&#127156;", "&#127199;"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access to object field with .  like this:

`object.field`

In your case you can use:

```js
let cards = [
    {value: "4", suit: "Hearts", weight: 4, cardFace: "&#127156;"},
    {value: "K", suit: "Clubs", weight: 10, cardFace: "&#127199;"}
]

cards.forEach(card => {
  console.log(card.cardFace);
})
```